# How to add permissions to windows user in samba on ubuntu server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba

I have this samba network drive configured in ubuntu server for my windows computer and i want to make it so i can read/write but other users can not read or write to the network drive. How can i edit the smb.conf so i can do this?
this is my smb.conf at the moment:

```
[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = /srv/samba/share
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0755
```

Answer (score 1):

To be thorough:

First, create a samba user if you haven't already:

```
useradd sambauser
smbpasswd -a sambauser
```

Enter and confirm the password for `sambauser`.

Change that part of your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to this:

```
[share]
comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
path = /srv/samba/share
valid users = sambauser
browsable = yes
writable = yes
write list = sambauser
create mask = 0755
```

Make sure that the directory and everything that might be inside has the proper ownership and permissions:

```
chown -R sambauser:sambauser /srv/samba/share
chmod -R 755 /srv/samba/share
```

Make sure that you have allowed `samba` through `selinux` with this command if it is enabled. If `selinux` is not enabled then you can skip this part:

```
chcon -R -t  samba_share_t /srv/samba/share
```

Lastly, make sure that the ports are open for `samba` on the firewall.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=445/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=139/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl restart firewalld
```

If using `iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
iptables-save
iptables-restore
```

Restart the samba service and then log in with the credentials of `sambauser`.

Comment: i get a error when running chcon -R -t  samba_share_t /srv/samba/share. the error says: chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file 'Misc'

Comment: @matthewtranmer Is `selinux` enabled on your system?

Comment: no it is not, how do i enable it?

Comment: @matthewtranmer If it's not enabled then you can skip that part. I'll update the answer and you can go ahead and connect if you've done everything else. Be sure that you restart the samba service first.

Comment: i still get the error message

Comment: @matthewtranmer What error?

Comment: when i try to access it on windows i get a error message saying (in brief)  \\192.168.1.144\share is not accessible

Comment: @matthewtranmer Make sure that `samba` is allowed through the firewall via my update. Then make sure that either `firewalld` or `iptables` are reloaded/restarted and that `samba` is also restarted. To be sure, run `netstat -tanp | grep smb` and make sure that `smbd` is listening.

Comment: Ok I’ll try it in the morning

Answer (score 0):

Turn off guest permissions and log into the shared drive with the owners credentials from the SAMBA machine to which owns the folder.

Comment: i get a error when i try to access it  it says: \\192.168.1.144\fileserver is not accessible

Comment: make sure that the share path is owned by the user

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: use the chown command to change owner of a file or folder. Look at the chown man page if you have questions about how to use chown.